# How to connect furniture without cam locks?

Tags: furniture

I am planning to build my own coffee table.
Is there any other way to connect furniture without using cam locks?
Because it's hard to align and requires skills.
Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. There's every other way imaginable; cam locks would be my absolute last choice of fastener, however. A mock-up diagram with dimensions of the lumber used would help us decide how you should attach everything.

Answer (score 3):

The subject of joining wood is vast.  Just look at the "woodworking joints"  Wikipedia article for a start. Usually cam locks are used for furniture built from kits such as IKEA.  Furniture made from scratch will use more traditional joinery techniques such as dovetails, mortise and tendon, tongue and groove, etc.

Comment: Thanks! Do you think that dowel joint is enough?

Comment: @martyr - no one can answer that without knowing the design of your furniture and its use  (i.e. what sort of loads you expect). If you have a plan in mind and have specific questions about joints or joining, you may find that the [Woodworking Stackexchange](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com) site is a good resource, but probably not for a  non-specific "I'm building a table, tell me how to join it" question.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Pocket-hole joinery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pocket-hole_joinery). Jigs are available to help you drill and guide in screws at an angle.

[image]

There's also standard [leg hardware](https://store.workshopsupply.com/catalogue/leg-table-hardware-kit-p-372.html):

[image]

For classic wood joints, I suggest asking this question over at [WoodWorking](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Hello, i wasn't aware of WoodWorking site. Thanks for helps and tips.

Comment: Based on the initial question, I'm guessing the author is a relative novice to woodworking, making this a good approach.  Pocket-hole joinery is relatively straightforward and is sufficiently strong when used correctly.  While many would argue the merits of more "traditional" joinery methods, a decent coffee table you can make today is often better than a craftsman quality, fully mortise and tenoned coffee table 5 years from now.